# JavaFX: Make TableColumn observe formatted Double with extractor functionality

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, number-formatting, extractor

I have a `TableView` poulated by an `ObservableList` of a custom object `FermentableInRecipe`, where one of the `TableColumn`s is defined to handle `Number`s, and should display values as a percentage.

The custom object is defined by this class:

```
public class FermentableInRecipe extends Fermentable {

    private DoubleProperty percentage = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    ...

    public Double getPercentage() {
        return this.percentage.getValue();
    }

    public void setPercentage(Double value) {
        if (value == null || value.isNaN() || value.isInfinite() || value > 1.0 || value < 0.0) {
            this.percentage.setValue(0.0);
        } else {
            this.percentage.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    public DoubleProperty percentageProperty() {
        if (percentage == null) {
            percentage = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        }
        return percentage;
    }
}
```

In my controller is the `TableView` object with child `TableColumn`.

```
@FXML
private TableView<FermentableInRecipe> tableviewFermentablesInRecipe;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FermentableInRecipe, Number> columnRecipeFermentablePercentage;
```

The `TableView` is populated by the following `ObservableList` of my custom object, which has been instantiated with an extractor.

```
private ObservableList<FermentableInRecipe> fermentablesInRecipe 
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[]{
            item.WeightProperty(), 
            item.isLateAdd(), 
            item.isBulkBought()
        });

tableviewFermentablesInRecipe.setItems(fermentablesInRecipe);
```

With the following usage of the `setCellValueFactory()` and `setCellFactory()` methods (which I based on [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977596/implement-spinner-in-tableview-to-show-edit-value-of-custom-object)), I have got the values to be displayed as I want them. However, it does not update whenever an element in the `ObservableList` is edited (as if it is ignoring my extractor). This behaviour does not occur when I observe the `SimpleDoubleProperty` in my custom object directly (but it would be an unformatted `Double`).

```
    final JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder percentageCellBuilder
            = JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder
                    .create()
                    .beanClass(FermentableInRecipe.class)
                    .name("percentage");

    columnRecipeFermentablePercentage.setCellValueFactory(item -> {
        try {
            return percentageCellBuilder.bean(item.getValue()).build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MasterController.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    });

    columnRecipeFermentablePercentage.setCellFactory(item -> 
            new PercentageCell<>()
    );
```

Here is the Percentage cell class:

```
public class PercentageCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Number> {

    NumberFormat percentageFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number percentage, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(percentage, empty);

        if (percentage == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setText(percentageFormat.format(percentage));
            setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is... How can I get the `TableColumn` to display the formatted number, and still have my extractor function properly?

Sorry if this is too big of a post, but I didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: Why are you using the `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` when you already have a JavaFX `DoubleProperty` in your `FermentableInRecipe` class? The `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` is designed for adapting a "bound Java bean property" to JavaFX.

Comment: I adapted it from the process I used to make a custom `TableCell` that housed a `Spinner` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977596/implement-spinner-in-tableview-to-show-edit-value-of-custom-object)). I now see how that would make sense for the spinner and not for a formatted number. I changed my `setCellValueFactory()` call to `columnRecipeFermentablePercentage.setCellValueFactory(item->item.getValue().percentageProperty());`. It now works as intended. I seem to have confused the meaning of the `setCellValueFactory()` method. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: The use of the `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` in the linked question has nothing at all to do with the `Spinner`.  It is there because the model class there isn’t using JavaFX properties.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have assumed. Well... now I don't quite understand why the `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` is needed for the custom spinner cell (in the link), because it works just as well when I pass the relevant `DoubleProperty` to the `setCellValueFactory()` method directly (in the same way that I mentioned above and in my answer).  This is obviously something I need to research more. Could you give me some keywords I could use to search for more info on this?

Comment: But in the question you linked (at least in the answer), the `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` is never referenced in the cell factory (which is as it should be). It is only referenced in the cell *value* factory. The cell value factory has to return an `ObservableValue` (so the table can observe it, and update if it changes); because you don't have JavaFX properties (observable values) in your model there, you have to use the adapter.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224091/getting-localdate-to-display-in-a-tableview-in-javafx/50224259#50224259 helps

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I'll give it a run-through asap.

Answer (score 0):

As @James_D pointed out, I was making unecessary use of `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` because my custom object already had a `DoubleProperty` I could have made use of.

To fix this silly mistake, I changed this...

```
final JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder percentageCellBuilder
        = JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder
                .create()
                .beanClass(FermentableInRecipe.class)
                .name("percentage");

columnRecipeFermentablePercentage.setCellValueFactory(item -> {
    try {
        return percentageCellBuilder.bean(item.getValue()).build();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MasterController.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
});
```

... into this...

```
columnRecipeFermentablePercentage.setCellValueFactory(item -> 
                                item.getValue().percentageProperty()
);
```

The automatic updating of the `TableView` contents via my extractor now works exactly as intended. Silly me.